# Toggling LED through button (ESP32 FreeRTOS) + binary semaphore

Tags: embedded, esp32, freertos, binary-semaphore

I had already done several projects using simple freertos ideas: led, button. Implementing semaphores, queues or some interrupt. I can't run this simple code tough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"

#include "driver/gpio.h"

#define BLINK_GPIO 21 //2
#define BUTTON_GPIO 0

void task_blink(void *pvParameters);
void task_botao(void *pvParameters);
//void wd_off_task(void *pvParameters);
SemaphoreHandle_t sem_sinc;

void app_main(void)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(BLINK_GPIO); // Configura o pino como IO
    gpio_set_direction(BLINK_GPIO,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT); // Configura o IO como saida

    gpio_pad_select_gpio(BUTTON_GPIO); // Configura o pino como IO
    gpio_set_direction(BUTTON_GPIO,GPIO_MODE_INPUT); // Configura o IO como entrada

    vSemaphoreCreateBinary(sem_sinc); // Cria o Semaforo
    xSemaphoreTake(sem_sinc,0); // Garante que inicializa com 0

    xTaskCreate(task_blink,"Task Blink",1024,NULL,2,NULL);
    printf("Task Blink Criada!!!\r\n");

    xTaskCreate(task_botao,"Task Botao",1024,NULL,2,NULL);
    printf("Task Botao Criada!!!\r\n");

    //xTaskCreate(wd_off_task,"Task desliga WD",1024,NULL,1,NULL);
}

void task_botao(void *pvParameters)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(gpio_get_level(BUTTON_GPIO) == 0)
        {
            while(gpio_get_level(BUTTON_GPIO) == 0){}
            printf("Botao Pressionado!!!\r\n");
            xSemaphoreGive(sem_sinc);
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }
    }
}

void task_blink(void *pvParameters)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(xSemaphoreTake(sem_sinc,portMAX_DELAY)==pdTRUE)
        {
            printf("Pisca Led!!!\r\n");
            if((gpio_get_level(BUTTON_GPIO) == 0))
                gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO, 1);
            else
                gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

**The issue**:

The code is built nicely, and the same for the flashing to ESP. As I press the button, it shows in the terminal the designed messages. See, the only problem here lies on I can't set the LED's level, toggling it! Because of this, all I can get is the LED turning on and turning off afterwards quickly(every time the semaphore syncronizes the 2 tasks).

I suspect it's all about some kind of config, related to this GPIO. (Although I'm using the reset port to read the button, I still think this is not the matter, because the port was properly configured on the lines above)

Comment: Your debounce delay is rather short if your tick interval is 1ms.  Moreover an asynchronous delay of one tick is deterministic, depending on when it starts in the tick interval it will be zero to 1 tick long.  A sensible denounce period would be about 20ms.  It only needs to be short enough to avoid missing "real" switch events, and I defy you to generate 50 operations per second!

Comment: Hi there! Reaaly thank for your help. I Improved this delay.. But it still doesnt work. Let me explain again the very point.  I d like to set the gpio level steady by pressing the button,  No matter it was done10 hours ago . It should only turn off, if the button was pressed another time. Unfortunelly, all im having is the esp devkit led blinking. And that is the case (in every code I implement, this phenomen occur). Im trying another strategy with this coode in the blink_task (oonce the semaphore was took, where uint_32 ctrl=0):  for(;;) {ctrl++;  gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO,ctrl%2);}

Comment: I appreciate it did not fix the problem;it was a comment, not an answer.  There is more than that that is wrong.

Comment: You should really delete that last comment.  It is ill-advised to post contact details, and answers by direct contact are not the Stack overflow way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch polling needs to detect transitions, but avoid erroneously detecting switch bounce as a valid transition.  For example:

```
#define BUTTON_DN = 0 ;
#define BUTTON_UP = 1 ;
#define POLL_DELAY = 50 ;

void task_botao(void *pvParameters)
{
    int button_state = gpio_get_level( BUTTON_GPIO ) ;
    
    for(;;)
    {
        int input_state = gpio_get_level( BUTTON_GPIO ) ;
        
        // If button pressed...
        if( input_state == BUTTON_DN && 
            button_state != BUTTON_UP )
        {
            button_state = BUTTON_DN ;

            // Signal button press event.
            xSemaphoreGive(sem_sinc ) ;
        }
        // otherwise if button released...
        else if( input_state == BUTTON_UP && 
                 button_state != BUTTON_DN )  
        {
            button_state = BUTTON_UP ;
        }
        
        // Delay to yield processor and 
        // avoid switch bounce on transitions 
        vTaskDelay( POLL_DELAY );
    }
}
```

The blinking task need not be reading the button input at all; not is it unnecessary, it is also a bad design:

```
void task_blink(void *pvParameters)
{
    int led_state = 0 ;
    gpio_set_level( BLINK_GPIO, led_state ) ;

    for(;;)
    {
        if( xSemaphoreTake( sem_sinc, portMAX_DELAY ) == pdTRUE )
        {
            led_state = !led_state ; 
            gpio_set_level( BLINK_GPIO, led_state ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider. Your thinking is logical, but there are some issues.

A button is a mechanical device and while you press it, you think it will be a straightforward 0 instead of 1 it’s not. If you have an oscilloscope, I recommend you to check the voltage level on the gpio input. Or google button bounce. And floating pins. Those two concepts should be clear. The processor is very straightforward in interpreting the values.

Example: https://hackaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/debounce_bouncing.png

Now your functions are in fact constantly checking the button status, somehow at the cost of processor time. For small projects not of an issue, but when they get bigger they are.

What you want to do is to setup an interrupt to the button status: at the moment the level changes it will fire some code. And it doesn’t have to double check the gpio status in two tasks, with the chance it will miss the status in the second (because of delays). It’s important to realize you are checking the same level twice now.

Not a problem now but maybe later: the stack size of the tasks is somehow small, make it a good use to always check if it’s enough by checking the current free size. Vague problems arise if it’s not.

Comment: Thanks RemyHx!! 
        ctrl++;
        gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO,ctrl%2);   // now im trying this strategy. This routine in inside the tasks's main loop , where ctrl is an unint_32.  Have any suggestions? By the way, the tips were very useful. I'm really on the way to test it using interrupts. Even tough I already know that this crazy behaviour will keep on. Ty a lot

Comment: Check this git: https://github.com/Mair/esp32-course/tree/master/_10_gpio/_10_3_Input_interupt

Comment: @caio_alBR ; The solution really does not require interrupts.  You'd still have to deal with switch bounce. only now you have a flurry of unwanted interrupts.  That can be resolved, but only by adding unnecessary complexity.  You might use an interrupt for a switch if it were time critical such a limit switch or emergency stop, but not for UI input.

Comment: An interrupt is not necessarily needed indeed, but constantly checking the gpio pins can take too much resources/time. Especially when the state change is short and with bigger projects. I personally like to use not too much of vtaskdelays and while loops, but it’s not the only way how things can or should be done.

Comment: Since the interrupt context has higher priority than any task, in a truly real time system, using interrupts for this may affect the timing of more critical tasks.  An RTOS is about meeting hard deadlines, and manual button pressed need not be acted on instantly or be polled particularly often.  Besides here you have not indicated how you handle switch bounce.  Switching off interrupts for a period is one way, but you then need a timer resource, which might be wasteful in this case.

Comment: Good point. It is crucial to keep the interrupt activated code as short as possible and accept a delay between that code and the actual executive task. Such a delay is not even possible to detect as a human being. A queue could be effective, even as a cheap and dirty debounce method. Personally I like the hardware approach (because I make the PCB myself), but for all kind of reasons this could be a software solution. I wouldn’t use a timer myself, because of the reason you mentioned.